# Remove first name using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I want it to display "Dr. House" instead of Dr. Greg house and I am only allowed to modify "const re = /^(\w+.\s)(\w+\s\w+)$/;". Can anyone help me?

here is the code

```
const userName = "Dr. Greg House"; // Code will also be tested with "Mr. Howard Wolowitz"

/* Your solution goes here */
const re = /^(\w+\.\s)(\w+\s\w+)$/;
const result = re.exec(userName);

console.log(result[1] + " " + result[2]);
```

Comment: Regular expressions aren’t designed for name parsing

Comment: In this regular expression, (\w) captures the first initial of the first name and (\w+) captures the last name. The result will display "Dr. House" for the given input. `^(\w+.\s)(\w)\w+\s(\w+)$`

Comment: I'd highly suggest you take a look at [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names – With Examples](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/). Like the Painter, `Pablo Picasso`, his full name was `Pablo Diego José Francisco de Paula Juan Nepomuceno María de los Remedios Cipriano de la Santísima Trinidad Ruiz y Picasso`. Good luck matching that correctly with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing groups only for the words you need to keep:

```js
const userName = "Dr. Greg House"; // Code will also be tested with "Mr. Howard Wolowitz"

/* Your solution goes here */
const re = /^(\w+\.)\s\w+\s(\w+)$/;
const result = re.exec(userName);

console.log(result[1] + " " + result[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A `.replace()` combined with a `.trim()` will do the job just as well:

```js
const names = ["Dr. Greg House", "Mr. Howard Wolowitz", "Dr. Amy Farrah Fowler"];
const res=names.map(n=>{
  return n.trim().replace(/\s+\S+/,"")
});

console.log(res);
```